# PHP loop with dyamic images from a folder list

Tags: php, foreach

I have a folder called loop-images which has a set of images. I also have the php loop below:

```
foreach ($feed as $feed_id => $feed_title){
    echo '<img src="/loop-images/01.jpg" border="0"><br>';
    echo '<a href="/?id='.$feed_id.'">'.$feed_title.'</a>';
}
```

In the loop I have a fixed image, However I am looking to use the image dynamically from the loop-images folder. So basically, on the first loop it should use the first image and so on. If it runs out of images in the loop then it starts from the first image again.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: sorry where do you get the id or title of a given image ? You've only the filename

Comment: @DiegoMariani the id and title is not for the image its part of a news feed, but while the news feed loop is happening, I am wanting to randomly show pictures which i have in that loop-images folder. Hope that makes sense

Comment: so your aim is to read all images into the `loop-images` folder and print them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something which you can try

```
    $directory = "/loop-images"; // path to loop images folder

    $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

    $imagescounter = 0; foreach ($feed as $feed_id => $feed_title){
    if($imagescounter>count($images)){
       $imagescounter = 0;
    }

    echo '<img src="/loop-images/'.$images[$imagescounter].'.jpg" border="0"><br>';
    echo '<a href="/?id='.$feed_id.'">'.$feed_title.'</a>';
    $imagescounter++; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're trying to accomplish is something like that.

Using the [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function and a regex to match all images using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) php function

```
foreach(scandir('/path/to/loop-images/') as $key => $file) {
    if (preg_match('/[\s\S]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|tiff|gif|bmp)/iu', $file)) {
        echo '<img src="loop-images/' . $file . '" border="0"><br>';
    }
}
```